# regex expression small letters and numbers

Tags: regex

I currently have this expression on my code

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d).*$/
```

Allowed

1. At least 1 lowercase letters
2. At least 1 number
3. It can start with either numbers or letters

Not allowed

- Spaces or any kind of other chars

I tried with `/S` but still spaces were welcomed

Example:

```
210d2cf6ada1937726c17f1ef41ab1
```

or

```
fssd2cf63ada1937726c17fef41ab1
```

those ex were random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negate matching of a blank space character:

```
^(?! )(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d).*$
```

Alternatively, use `\S` instead of `.`:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)\S*$
```

Comment: works perfect. can you tell me how to block any other special character?

Comment: Instead of `\S`, put `[a-z\d]`